# Evaluate polynomials by reading it from a file

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials

I would like to read and evaluate a polynomial from a txt file that is given in the following format,

**3x^3-4x^1+5**

- So the above equation should be evaulated by the program as follows,

**Coefficients:** [3,0,-4,5]

So far I could able to parse the string and created two different lists that store coefficients and the degrees as follows,

**Coefficients:** [3,-4,5] **--> They are the coeffs of x^3, x^1, and x^0**

**Degrees:** [3,1]

However I could not evaluate (**i.e.** P(1) = 3(1^3)-4(1^1)+5 = 4) the polynomial with these extracted values. I would like to use numpy, yet the formats do not match.

Can anyone help me how can I obtain the required format for utilizing numpy?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately your question is too broad. Stack oveflow is no a code-writing service, it helps you solving specific problems. Read [ask] and refine your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can put the constant term (coefficient of x^0) in your `deg` list, then you can do this:

```
coeffs = [3,-4,5]
degs = [3,1,0]
_coeffs = [0]*(max(degs)+1)
for i,deg in enumerate(degs):
    _coeffs[deg] = coeffs[i]

p = np.poly1d(_coeffs[::-1])
```

Then:

```
p(1)
4
```

That is, you just need to create a list of coefficients in which the coefficient appears at the index of the degree.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the file as two separate lists, merge them into a single one. Then use `polyval` from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

p = [3,0,-4,5]
np.polyval(p,1)
```

Gives you 4 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This is without using numpy:-

```
function eval_poly(coef,degree,value_of_x):
    num = 0
    while num < len(coef)-1:
        answer = coef[num]*value_of_x^degree[num]
        num += 1
    answer += coef[-1]
    return answer
```